# Make properties of a control available for binding externally

Tags: wpf, data-binding, controls

I have a control implemented like this:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Browse..." Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Load File" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
    </Grid>
```

This is designed to be used as a stand alone control. How can i allow consumers of this control to bind to the `Text` property of the textbox for example. Do i need to implement my own dependwncy properties and handle the actual textbox data myself, or is there a way to allow consumers to bind directly to internal properties?

Answer (score 2):

If this is a control meant to be used by others in XAML, then yes, you should expose your properties as DependencyProperties. This allows anyone using your control to use bindings etc on your control.

```
public partial class MyControl: UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FileNameProperty = 
           DependencyProperty.Register("FileName ", typeof(string), typeof(MyControl));

    public string FileName
    {
        get 
        {
            return (string )GetValue(FileNameProperty ); 
        }
        set 
        {
            SetValue(FileNameProperty , value); 
        }
    }
}
```

You can then bind your own textbox in the control markup to the same property:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MyControl}}, Path=FileName}" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Browse..." Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Load File" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi make public property in your control as

```
public string PropertyName
       {
           get{return _propertyName;}
           set{
               _propertyName=value;
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(textboxName,TextBox.TextProperty,new Binding(){Mode=BindingMode.TwoWay,Source=PropertyName})
              }
       }
```

and let the consumer simply to specify PropertyName="PropertyToBind" .I hope this will help.textboxName is the name of your control TextBox.